# Do you use the "global" statement in Python?

Tags: python, global

I was reading a question about the Python *global* statement ( ["Python scope"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146359/python-scope) ) and I was remembering about how often I used this statement when I was a Python beginner (I used *global* a lot) and how, nowadays, years later, I don't use it at all, ever. I even consider it a bit "un-pythonic".

Do you use this statement in Python ? Has your usage of it changed with time ?

Answer (score 59):

I use 'global' in a context such as this:

```
_cached_result = None
def myComputationallyExpensiveFunction():
    global _cached_result
    if _cached_result:
       return _cached_result

    # ... figure out result

    _cached_result = result
    return result
```

I use 'global' because it makes sense and is clear to the reader of the function what is happening. I also know there is this pattern, which is equivalent, but places more cognitive load on the reader:

```
def myComputationallyExpensiveFunction():
    if myComputationallyExpensiveFunction.cache:
        return myComputationallyExpensiveFunction.cache

    # ... figure out result

    myComputationallyExpensiveFunction.cache = result
    return result
myComputationallyExpensiveFunction.cache = None
```

Comment: I tend to use the decorator module's 'memoize' function in instances like this but I can't fault the clarity of your global usage :)

Comment: I didn't know about the possibility of defining an attribute of a function such as myComputationallyExpensiveFunction.cache and using it inside the function body, thanks!

Comment: I had never heard of assigning an attribute to a function, that is great stuff!  Thanks!

Comment: 2nd line of 2nd example should be "if getattr(myComputationallyExpensiveFunction, "cache", None):", otherwise AttributeError.

Comment: @AndyGrover I didn't need to do that, the code works fine without it and I don't see any AttributeError (?)

Answer (score 15):

I've never had a legit use for the statement in any production code in my 3+ years of professional use of Python and over five years as a Python hobbyist. Any state I need to change resides in classes or, if there is some "global" state, it sits in some shared structure like a global cache.

Comment: Was thinking of using global for the first time specifically for creating a global cache. Your response makes it seem as if you are using something other than the global keyword to create and maintain a global cache... Could you share how you achieved this?

Answer (score 10):

I've used it in situations where a function creates or sets variables which will be used globally.  Here are some examples:

```
discretes = 0
def use_discretes():
    #this global statement is a message to the parser to refer 
    #to the globally defined identifier "discretes"
    global discretes
    if using_real_hardware():
        discretes = 1
...
```

or

```
file1.py:
    def setup():
        global DISP1, DISP2, DISP3
        DISP1 = grab_handle('display_1')
        DISP2 = grab_handle('display_2')
        DISP3 = grab_handle('display_3')
        ...

file2.py:
    import file1

    file1.setup()
    #file1.DISP1 DOES NOT EXIST until after setup() is called.
    file1.DISP1.resolution = 1024, 768
```

Answer (score 8):

In my view, as soon as you feel the need to use global variables in a python code, it's a great time to stop for a bit and work on refactoring of your code.
Putting the `global` in the code and delaying the refactoring process might sound promising if your dead-line is close, but, believe me, you're not gonna go back to this and fix unless you really have to - like your code stopped working for some odd reason, you have to debug it, you encounter some of those `global` variables and all they do is mess things up.

So, honestly, even it's allowed, I would as much as I can avoid using it. Even if it means a simple classes-build around your piece of code.

Answer (score 3):

Objects are the prefered way of having non-local state, so global is rarely needed. I dont think the upcoming nonlocal modifier is going to be widely used either, I think its mostly there to make lispers stop complaining :-)

Answer (score 3):

I use it for global options with command-line scripts and 'optparse':

my main() parses the arguments and passes those to whatever function does the work of the script... but writes the supplied options to a global 'opts' dictionary.

Shell script options often tweak 'leaf' behavior, and it's inconvenient (and unnecessary) to thread the 'opts' dictionary through every argument list.

Answer (score 2):

Rarely. I've yet to find a use for it at all.

Comment: I have a VERBOSE const var, being set in command line (argparsing).

It needs to be passed to most functions in a module. It is a "read-only" var on the module level.

Isn't declaring it global better than passing it to almost every single function which needs to read it only for logging purposes?

Answer (score 2):

It can be useful in threads for sharing state (with locking mechanisms around it).

However, I rarely if ever use it.

Answer (score 2):

I've used it in quick & dirty, single-use scripts to automate some one-time task. Anything bigger than that, or that needs to be reused, and I'll find a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

Once or twice. But it was always good starting point to refactor.

Answer (score 1):

I avoid it and we even have a [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857) rule that forbids it in our production code. I actually believe it shouldn't even exist at all.

Answer (score 0):

If I can avoid it, no. And, to my knowledge, there is always a way to avoid it. But I'm not stating that it's totally useless either