# python multi-threading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

i have a problem when using my code with threading, the problem is apparently that the variables i define outside of the threading part aren't defined inside the threading part, here is my code:

```
import sys
import socket
from time import sleep
import threading

ip = raw_input ("please insert host ip: ")
port = input ("please insert port to fuzz: ")
header = raw_input ("please enter the header you want to fuzz, put & in the place you want to fuzz: ")
packet = raw_input ("what string would you like to fuzz the header with? : ")
multi = input ("in what jumps would you liike to multiply the string ? : ")
process = input ("please insert number of threads: ")
host = ip, port
char = packet * multi
a = 1

class ConnectionThread ( threading.Thread ):
    def run ( self ):
        while a > 0:
            try:
                s = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                s.connect((host))
                header = header.replace("&", packet)
                s.send(header)
                s.settimeout(7)
                data = s.recv(4)
                if data > 0:
                    print "got awnser"
                else:
                    print "no awnser"   
                sleep(0.1) 
                print "Fuzzing With:", header
                header = header.replace (packet, "&")
                packet = char + packet 
                s.close()
            except Exception as e:
                print e   
                s.close()
                sys.exit(0)
for x in xrange ( process ):
   ConnectionThread().start()
```

and i get this as return

```
local variable 'header' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to give your ConnectionThread class the attributes that you want to pass to it. At the top of the class just put in a **init** method, this will define the variable that you want to pass to the run method:

```
import sys
import socket
from time import sleep
import threading

class ConnectionThread ( threading.Thread ):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ip = raw_input ("please insert host ip: ")
        self.port = input ("please insert port to fuzz: ")
        self.header = raw_input ("please enter the header you want to fuzz, put & in the place you want to fuzz: ")
        self.packet = raw_input ("what string would you like to fuzz the header with? : ")
        self.multi = input ("in what jumps would you liike to multiply the string ? : ")
        self.process = input ("please insert number of threads: ")
        self.host = self.ip, self.port
        self.char = self.packet * self.multi
        self.a = 1

    def run ( self ):
        while self.a > 0:
            try:
                s = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                s.connect((self.host))
                self.header = self.header.replace("&", self.packet)
                s.send(self.header)
                s.settimeout(7)
                data = s.recv(4)
                if data > 0:
                    print "got awnser"
                else:
                    print "no awnser"   
                sleep(0.1) 
                print "Fuzzing With:", header
                self.header = self.header.replace (self.packet, "&")
                self.packet = self.char + self.packet 
                s.close()
            except Exception as e:
                print e   
                s.close()
                sys.exit(0)

for x in xrange ( ConnectionThread.process ):
   ConnectionThread().start()
```

have a look at how classes work at:

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html

for additional information.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: this code for some odd reason wont work, it justs crash with this error : import: unable to grab mouse `': Resource temporarily unavailable @ error/xwindow.c/XSelectWindow/9052.
from: can't read /var/mail/time
import: unable to grab mouse `': Resource temporarily unavailable @ error/xwindow.c/XSelectWindow/9052.
./fuzzy.py: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./fuzzy.py: line 6: `class ConnectionThread ( threading.Thread ):'
from: can't read /var/mail/time
./fuzzy.py: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./fuzzy.py: line 6: `class ConnectionThread ( threading.Thread ):'

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `global` to signify the variable is a global one. See, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146557/do-you-use-the-global-statement-in-python)

For example, add the following to `run` (above the `if`):

```
global host, header, ... # All the other variables you use
```

Comment: i read your link for the global function discussion , but i dont understand how to use it in my code

Comment: I think the essence of the discussion is: don't use it! Use a function for the gathering of all the parameters from the command line and let it return a dict or whatever you prefer, use it as parameter when you initialise the thread (add an __init__) and then access them as object attribute (self.header or self. parameters['header'] depending on the way you do)