# When do I need to use the global keyword in python

Tags: python

Okay, so I've had this really annoying problem where a variable got set locally but then outside of that function reverted to it's old self (in this case None), but at the same time I could manipulate other variables and still can without using the "global" keyword.

I can't provide the real code for this but it goes something like this:

```
foo = {}
foo_foo = {}
bar = None


def changes_foo():
    ...do some stuff to foo...

class EditThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        setup()

    def run(self):
       for key, value in foo.items():
           do_update_task(key, value)

    def do_update_task(self, key, value):
         ...do some editing too foo...
         del foo[key]
         bar = [key, value]
         foo_foo[key] = value

def print_the_bar():
    print bar
```

Please note that all the operations on `foo` and `foo_foo` works just fine, but bar is still None when I call `print_the_bar`, and I've had lots of print statements in my code to verify that bar inside of `do_update_task` indeed has the correct values and isn't None.

Could someone please explain to me why it is so?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them

Comment: My point is that I can still make changes to both foo and foo_foo but when I make changes to bar it only recides in the local scope. I'm more than willing to accept that I'm not a seasoned pythonista, my question is why do I keep getting this error.

Comment: "Could someone please explain to me why it is so?" In two words: variable scoping. In more words: [link](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/scopes.html)

Comment: "when do I need a global variable?" -- Only when you need to rethink your program design.

Comment: Yes yes, we all now that global variables are pure evil... :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do you use the "global" statement in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146557/do-you-use-the-global-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you do things to foo and foo_foo, you're not changing the reference:

```
foo = {}
foo['key'] = 'stuff'
```

`foo` still refers to the same object as before; it just now contains more data.

```
bar = ['key', 'value']
```

This **reassigns** `bar` to refer to a new object (the list with two elements).

However, when that line is encountered inside a function, it creates a **local** reference `bar` unless you say `global bar`.  In effect, you have two different variables named `bar`: the global and the local.

Saying `global bar` tells Python to use the global version of `bar` rather than creating a new local variable with the same name.

Generally, if you are modifying global variables, you should state `global varname` for each one to avoid accidentally creating a local.

Or, you can use a class:

```
class State(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = {}
        self.foo_foo = {}
        self.bar = None

state = State()

def fn():
    state.bar = ['key', 'value']
```

Comment: Thank you for a good answer that explains why. I will accept your answer as soon as i can.

Comment: +1 for the only answer that doesn't claim you can't modify global variables without the global keyword; of course you can modify them, you just can't globally re-bind the name with `=`.

Comment: @Wooble Good point .. I think I will actually delete my answer just based on that :)

Answer (score 25):

If you only need to *read* the value of a global variable in a function, you don't need the global keyword:

```
x = 3
def f():
    print x
```

If you *ever* set the value of a global variable, you need the keyword so that you don't create a local variable:

```
x = 3
def f():
    global x
    x = 5

f()
print x
```

Comment: Thanks, this difference was really revealing to me!

Comment: +1 for conciseness and clarity. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081308/why-is-the-global-keyword-not-required-in-this-case) on how this doesn't work as many would expect for dictionaries.

Comment: Understanding the difference between assigning to a *name* (`x = 5`) and mutation (often disguised as a assignment like `x[...] = 5`) is fundamental to understanding how Python works.

Answer (score 0):

Variables you define in function are accessible only from this function's body.

Answer (score 0):

You can read variables from the global scope from within a function, but you can't modify their values without using the "global" keyword.

When you attempt to set `bar =[key, value]`, a new `bar` variable is added to your function's namespace. From then on, `bar` references this new variable, and not the global one.

Although you can read the global `bar`'s value, once you attempt to re-assign it a value from within your function, you've actually created a new `bar` and are not acting on the global one.