# Why is the global keyword not required in this case?

Tags: python, global-variables

```
cache = {}
def func():
    cache['foo'] = 'bar'
print cache['foo']
```

output

```
bar
```

Why does this work and why doesn't it require use of the `global` keyword?

Comment: `global` is not required for mutable objects.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Care to add a reference?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary That's simply untrue. Try this with a list and it won't work and lists and mutable! mylist = [] def f1(): mylist = ['a']; mylist is still empty if you print it outside of f1()

Comment: @samsamara That's not what I meant, with `mylist = ['a']` you're explicitly defining a new local variable. Perform a mutation instead, like `mylist.append(10)` etc

Comment: Yes if you do a mutation like that, it is going to work as you are only accessing it. But say if i change my function to accept a list as a parameter, `def f1(mylist): mylist = mylist + ['a']`; where I'm mutating the list using the assignment operator. And I have `mylist = ['s']` and I call `f1(mylist)`. Now as lists are mutable and you passing list object to `f1()` yet it is still not mutating `mylist`.

Comment: So I guess the better way is to think in terms of if/how you are using the assignment operator inside a function with parameters..?

Comment: @samsamara `mylist = mylist + ['a']` isn't a mutation, it results in creation of completely new list.

Answer (score 25):

Because you are not *assigning* to `cache`, you are changing the dictionary itself instead. `cache` is still pointing to the dictionary, thus is itself unchanged. The line `cache['foo'] = 'bar'` translates to `cache.__setitem__('foo', 'bar')`. In other words, the value of `cache` is a python `dict`, and that value is itself mutable.

If you tried to change what `cache` refers to by using `cache = 'bar'` instead, you would be changing what `cache` points to and then you need the `global` keyword.

Perhaps this older answer of mine to a similar question helps you understand the difference: [Python list doesn't reflect variable change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080552/python-list-doesnt-reflect-variable-change-new-to-python/12080644#12080644).

Comment: So this way one can defy the whole point of having the `global` keyword ?

Comment: @BunnyRabbit: The *point* of having the `global` keyword is for the python compiler to know what structure to change. Fully understanding why that is needed requires delving into the internal workings of Python (`locals()` versus `globals()` and byte code and such). Nothing is being defied here, a dynamic language is not about trying to prevent you from modifying globals. :-)