# why is python function capable of mutating non-global list?

Tags: python

```
myList = [5, 2]
def foo():
    myList[0] = 6
```

In the example above, `myList` is still mutated, though it is non-global and not passed in by parameter. This doesn't work however, if the variable is not a list.

Comment: I thought that if you want to mutate something in a function you have to call: global myList?

Comment: only when you reassign new value to given name. You are not in this case.

Comment: Not when mutating elements of a list `list[0] = 4` will work while `list = [4, 5]` will not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262920/understanding-pythons-call-by-object-style-of-passing-function-arguments

Comment: This question isn't a duplicate of the linked question, because the other question is about argument passing in Python and here no arguments are passed.

Comment: Also see http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @mkrieger1 I agree the questions are different, but the answers of the linked question explain the core concept of Python's names & objects that also apply here.

Comment: Here is a more appropriate duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575196

Comment: Maybe this one is a better dupe target: [Why is the global keyword not required in this case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081308/why-is-the-global-keyword-not-required-in-this-case) The OP's code in that question uses a dict instead of a list, but the principle's the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope rules are roughly like this:

- Local scope: you define the variable inside a function
- Enclosing scope: your function is inside another function (or multiple layers of functions), and one of the higher (enclosing) functions declared the variable
- Global scope: the global scope (module or file)
- Built-in: Any built-in values native to Python

This is known as the LEGB rule.

In your case, it is because you are not assigning a value to the name `myList` inside of `foo()`. You are only assigning a value to the `0` index of an existing list. Therefore the global value of `myList` is the scope you are using.

Answer (score 2):

`myList` is a global variable, though. It exists in the context of `foo`, where you access and modify one of its elements.

```
myList = [0, 5]

def foo():
    myList[0] = 6

print('Before foo: {}'.format(myList))
foo()
print('After foo: {}'.format(myList))
```

**Output**

```
Before foo: [0, 5]
After foo: [6, 5]
```

> This doesn't work however, if the variable is not a list.

I assume that you tried something similar to the following:

```
a = 0

def bar():
    a = 6

print('Before bar: {}'.format(a))
bar()
print('After bar: {}'.format(a))
```

**Output**

```
Before bar: 0
After bar: 0
```

In this case, you don't observe any change in the *global* variable `a` because within `bar` you're assigning to a *new local variable* `a` which [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the global variable of the same name. You set the *local variable* `a` to 6, which has no effect as the variable is discarded as soon as the function ends.

You can show that even simple integers declared in the global scope can be accessed within function scopes by running something like the following. In this case, we specify that the function should modify an existing global variable `b` rather than assigning to a new local one.

```
b = 0

def baz():
    global b
    b = 6

print('Before baz: {}'.format(b))
baz()
print('After baz: {}'.format(b))
```

**Output**

```
Before baz: 0
After baz: 6
```

Comment: Example of `global` keyword might be helpful here since it shows how one _can_ assign to a global variable from the local scope. Python just assumes you don't normally mean that (and has no syntax for explicitly declaring a variable)

Comment: @pvg Step ahead of you. :)