# Change variable in function (Python 3.x)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

If you have python code like this:

```
thing = "string"
def my_func(variable):
    variable = input("Type something.")

my_func(thing)

print(thing)
```

Then the variable 'thing' will just return 'string' and not what the new input is. How can I change it without listing the actual variable name?

Comment: You shuld return a value from your function and assign it to the variable.  `thing = my_func()`

Comment: The parameters that you are passing by value, you must return the value and assign it again to the variable: `thing = "string"
def my_func(variable):
    variable = input("Type something.")
    return variable

thing = my_func(thing)

print(thing)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: functions to change values 'in place'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22338671/python-functions-to-change-values-in-place)

Answer (score 0):

> You have problems with scopes of variables.

Taking in the `thing` as a variable inside your function isn't any useful here as it can't be changed just by calling any function until you specifically define the function to change only the value of `thing`.

You can define it in one way as:

```
thing = "string"
def my_func():
    global thing #As thing has a global scope you have to tell python to modify it globally
    thing = input("Type something:")
>>>my_func()
>>>Type something: hello world
>>>print(thing)
>>>'Hello world'
```

But the above method will only work for the `thing` variable.  And not on any other variables passed to it, but a function like below will work on everything.

```
thing = "string"
def my_func():
    a = input("Type something."))
    return a
>>>thing = my_func()
>>>Type something: Hello world
>>>print(thing)
>>>'Hello world'
```

Comment: It is not appropriate to use the name of a function as a variable: `input = input("Type something."))`. what is `a`?

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry, I corrected it, any improvements you can suggest?

Comment: The use of global variables can bring problems that are difficult to track, so I avoid using them and recommend them unless the variable is unique, and I do not recommend it for beginners because they tend to abuse them. :D