# Python: unusual behaviour dictionary update method

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I am writing a script which builds a dictionary, and I observe a strange behaviour.

I will describe it below with a small example.

```
def test_f(parameter):
    parameter.update({'watermelon':'22'})
    return parameter

fruits = {'apple':20, 'orange': 35, 'guava': 12}
new_fruits = test_f(fruits)
```

In short, I have a dictionary which I pass to a function, `test_f`. The function appends a new dictionary to the input and returns it. I capture the output of the function in a variable called `new_fruits`. This however changes the original variable `fruits` too.

Why does the original variable `fruits` changes? 
Am I using the `update` method in an incorrect way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you are using it right.

But lists, dictionaries etc are mutable types. And they will get updated even if you change them in a local scope. That because, python actually pass parameters by names, rather by values.

Read more from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15078615/5019169).

Solution:

I will suggest you to make a new copy of dictionary and pass it as a parameter of your function. Use `copy.deepcopy` to copy the dictionary.

Change your function call like below:

```
import copy 

fruits = {'apple':20, 'orange': 35, 'guava': 12}
new_fruits = test_f(copy.deepcopy(fruits))
```

Comment: Glad to know it helped. You can tick the green mark on the left top of my answer to mark it as accepted.