# Python code produces incorrect results without using the .COPY() function

Tags: python, logic

I have this code.

```
List1 = [{'pg_id': 100, "group_name": "test1", "product_price": 100}, {'pg_id': 200, "group_name": "test2", "product_price": 200}]
List2 = [{'lowest_price': 20}]

FINAL_DICT = {}
for latest_lowest in List1:
    for idx, coupon_related__product in enumerate(List2):
        if coupon_related__product['lowest_price'] < latest_lowest['product_price']:
            FINAL_DICT[ latest_lowest['pg_id'] ] = coupon_related__product
            FINAL_DICT[ latest_lowest['pg_id'] ]['group_name'] = latest_lowest['group_name']
            print("Group name is %s"%(latest_lowest['group_name']))

for PG_ID, LOWEST_PRICED_PRODUCT_THIS_PG in FINAL_DICT.iteritems():
    print(LOWEST_PRICED_PRODUCT_THIS_PG)
```

My desired output in terminal is

```
Group name is test1
Group name is test2
{'lowest_price': 20, 'group_name': 'test2'}
{'lowest_price': 20, 'group_name': 'test1'}
```

But it outputs

```
Group name is test1
Group name is test2
{'lowest_price': 20, 'group_name': 'test2'}
{'lowest_price': 20, 'group_name': 'test2'}
```

If I change

```
FINAL_DICT[ latest_lowest['pg_id'] ] = coupon_related__product
```

to

```
FINAL_DICT[ latest_lowest['pg_id'] ] = coupon_related__product.copy()
```

Then it produces correct output which I want.

My question is, why all of the dictionaries in `FINAL_DICT` has `group_name=test2` when I don't use `.copy()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line:

```
FINAL_DICT[ latest_lowest['pg_id'] ] = coupon_related__product
```

assigns a dictionary to your entry. The next line:

```
FINAL_DICT[ latest_lowest['pg_id'] ]['group_name'] = latest_lowest['group_name']
```

changes the group name, but the reference of the dict is the last dictionary you assigned to, so the reference is shared.

that's why you have to make an copy of the dict so references are independent:

```
FINAL_DICT[ latest_lowest['pg_id'] ] = coupon_related__product.copy()
```

now modifying `FINAL_DICT[ latest_lowest['pg_id'] ]['group_name']` doesn't change the values of others `FINAL_DICT[ latest_lowest['pg_id'] ]`

Comment: What is this thing is called in Python? can you possible provide a very simple example code?

Comment: "this thing", you mean references ? example code of what?

Comment: Is “freeze” actual pythonic term?

Comment: nope. It's called making a copy. not sure if it's really python-related

Answer (score 1):

In Python dictionaries are mutable objects and are therefore not copied by default. You can read more about this here: [python dictionary passed as an input to a function acts like a global in that function rather than a local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078519/python-dictionary-passed-as-an-input-to-a-function-acts-like-a-global-in-that-fu)

If the whole pass by name vs pass by value vs pass by reference thing is too confusing then all you need to know is that Python does not normally make a copy of a `list` or `dict` when assigning values using `=`. When you want to make a copy of a `list` or `dict` you need to explicitly tell Python you would like a copy. So in summary

```
x = {"hello": "world"}
y = x
y["hello"] = "not world"
print("x is " + str(x))
print("y is " + str(y))

> x is {'hello': 'not world'}
> y is {'hello': 'not world'}
```

vs

```
x = {"hello": "world"}
y = x.copy()
y["hello"] = "not world"
print("x is " + str(x))
print("y is " + str(y))

> x is {'hello': 'world'}
> y is {'hello': 'not world'}
```