# Why is it that a function can modify global object attributes without an explicit global declaration?

Tags: python, global-variables

I am struggling to understand why a local function in Python 3 can seemingly modify global object attributes but not variables. If we consider object attributes to be variables attached to objects, this behavior appears very inconsistent and I cannot understand why the language behaves in this way.

1. We can create some class and use a function to modify an attribute of that class without anything like a global declaration of that attribute.

If we have some code:

```
class Integer:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.value = number

n = Integer(20)
print(n.value) # display value at initialization

def increase_n():
    n.value += 1

increase_n()
print(n.value) # display value after calling increase_n
```

Running this code would result in the following output:

```
20
21
```

2. We cannot do the same with a variable. An explicit global declaration must be used.

If we have some code:

```
k = 6
print(k) # display value after assignment

def increase_k():
    global k
    k += 2

increase_k()
print(k) # display value after calling increase_k
```

Running the above code results in:

```
6
8
```

Note that foregoing the global declaration for the second example would result in an error.

I am hoping someone can enlighten me. I am sure there must be some fundamental misunderstanding on my part. Why are variables and attributes treated so differently? Why is this good/bad?

Comment: Also related: [Global dictionaries don't need keyword global to modify them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14323817/11082165)

Comment: In the first example, if you will do `n = Integer(21)` without `global` you will have the same problem...

Answer (score 2):

The thing that the `global` keyword does is allow you to push a local variable (i.e. a *name*) assignment into the global (outermost) namespace.  By default, a variable exists in the namespace of the scope in which you assign a value to it; `global` overrides that.

You can *reference* a variable from an outer scope without needing any special keyword; `global` is only significant for the assignment operation.  Once you have a reference to the associated object, if it's mutable, you can freely mutate it, regardless of how you got that reference or where the object was created.

No `global` declaration is needed to affect the attribute `n.value` because it lives within the namespace of the object that `n` references, not the global namespace.  The fact that `n` itself is a variable in the global namespace is immaterial; you could do:

```
def increase_n():
    local_n = n  # local_n is local, n is still global
    local_n.value += 1
```

and it would have the same effect because `local_n` and `n` reference the same `Integer` object.

Comment: This is a really good explanation and has definitely increased my understanding of what is actually occurring. Thank you! However, I still have some fogginess surrounding the problem. If k is actually an instance of the class int, then why can your explanation not be applied to the second example too? Is it because k += 1 is actually assigning a new value to k instead of incrementing it? Any additional insight appreciated.

Comment: That's exactly it!  An `int` is immutable; when you do `k += 1` you're not mutating an int object, you're creating a new one and then assigning it to the name `k`.  You can observe the difference by assigning another name to `k` (e.g. `j = k`) and then doing `k += 1`.  `j` will still have the original value because it still points to the original object.  When you do `n.value += 1` what you're doing is mutating `n` by calling `n.__setattr__('value', n.value + 1)`.