# list and array is global by default in python3.6?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, global-variables

Just a simple code below:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array([1,2])
y=[1,2]
L=1

def set_L(x,y,L):
    x[0]+=1
    y[0]+=1
    L+=1
    print(id(x))
    print(id(y))
    print(id(L))
```

I found that array x and list y is the same in the function set_L(), does this mean by default list and array are global variables? however variable L is not global in the function set_L(). I am confusing that why Python is designed like this?

Comment: You can find the answer in the duplicate

Comment: The difference is one of mutability.

Comment: @hpaulj while mutability can affect the consequences, it is irrelevant with regards to scope and the semantics of assignment

Comment: This question conflates two things - variable scope, and how `+=` modifies an object.  Arrays and lists are mutable and can change without changing `id`, a scalar is not.  `id(L)` is the `id` of its value, `id(1)` or `id(2)` (and in Cython small positive integers have a unique id).

Answer (score 0):

x[0]+=1 and y[0]+=1 just modify the existing object, while L+=1 is an assignment and creates a new local reference. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11867500/7662112