# Python: Signal handler closure not capturing environment

Tags: python, python-2.7, signals

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371361/using-variables-in-signal-handler-require-global) answered post that seems to indicate closures installed as signal handlers should capture their environment, however I'm not seeing that (using Python 2.7). For example:

```py
import os
import signal
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid:
        signal.pause()
    else:
        sigint = False

        def handler(s, f):
            # global sigint
            print "sigint: {}".format(sigint)
            print "Signal handler"
            sigint = True

        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)

        signal.pause()
        if sigint:
            print "Caught sigint, sleeping briefly"
            time.sleep(2)
        print "exiting..."
```

Which running and triggering with ^C raises `UnboundedLocalError: local variable 'sigint' referenced before assignment` in the child. Uncommenting the `global` declaration fixes this. Clearly this is at odds with the aforementioned post, is the previous post simply incorrect, or am I doing something wrong here?

EDIT: Also the forking here is entirely extraneous, I was intending to investigate a different behavior when I noticed this one and just took the little script verbatim. The `else` block can replace the entire main thread to achieve the same result.

Comment: What is the argument s in the handler?

Comment: @fiacre just placeholders for the standard signal handler arguments. Python signal handlers are always passed `signum, frame` by default, specifying the signal which triggered that handler and the call stack frame which was interrupted. I don't use either here and got tired of writing out "signum, frame" over and over.

Comment: that's my point, if the signal's number is being sent as an argument, why are you defining it outside the handler?

Comment: @fiacre The `sigint` variable is simply a flag to indicate that the handler has been invoked. It has nothing to do with the signal number. I could name it `foobar` to the same effect.