# Creating global variable in python 3 from functions

Tags: python, html, variables, global, python-3.3

I was wondering why I can't access the variable: "variable_for_raw_data" after the function ends.  The code is like this:

```
def htmlfrom(Website_URL):
    import urllib.request
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(Website_URL)
    variable_for_raw_data =(input("What will this data be saved as: "))
    global variable_for_raw_data
    variable_for_raw_data = response.read()
```

Now why can't I access the variable "variable_for_raw_data" after the functions ends?

Things to note:

Python 3.3
urllib NOT urllib2

Comment: You should be able to access it.  Show us the code where you try to access it.

Comment: htmlfrom("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552601/creating-global-variable-in-python-3-from-functions")
What will this data be saved as: html_stackoverflow
>>> print(html_stackoverflow)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    print(html_stackoverflow)
NameError: name 'html_stackoverflow' is not defined

Comment: You can see I attempted to print(thevariablename) and I got the error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    print(html_stackoverflow)
NameError: name 'html_stackoverflow' is not defined

Comment: Hmm, can you make one paste in the original post, with the same variable names?  You're switching the names, so it's not clear what's going on.  Unless the problem is that the function creates `variable_for_raw_data`, and you are trying to access `html_stackoverflow`.

Comment: Yes.  I feel very stupid.  I was trying to access the wrong variable!!!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to dynamically create variables, I would imagine that your code looks something like this.

```
def htmlfrom(website_url):
    import urllib.request
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(website_url)
    variable_for_raw_data =(input("What will this data be saved as: "))
    global variable_for_raw_data
    variable_for_raw_data = response.read()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    htmlfrom("www.stackoverflow.com")

    #html_stackoverflow is never created it is the value
    #of variable_for_raw_data before variable_for_raw_data
    #is overridden by response.read()

    #entering information into input doesn't create a variable
    print(html_stackoverflow)
```

Here's how I would do it:

```
import urllib.request

def htmlfrom(website_url): 
    '''
       docstrings
    '''

    response = urllib.request.urlopen(website_url)
    variable_for_raw_data = response.read()
    return variable_for_raw_data

if __name__ == "__main__":

    file_name = input("What will this data be saved as: ")
    html_from_website = htmlfrom("www.stackoverflow.com")

        with open(file_name, 'w') as f: 
        f.write(html_from_website)
```

**Explanation**

if you have your import statement inside the function it is only accessable inside the
function (i.e. other functions can't access it)

```
import urllib.request
```

[PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) has guidelines on how things should be named in python
CamelCase is usually reserved for class names

```
def htmlfrom(website_url): 
    '''
        docstring 
    '''
```

[Docstrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) are usually a good idea.

Check out this question for more information on the proper use of [globals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/146557/322909).
Based on what I know about your situation I don't think you need to use them.

```
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(website_url)
    variable_for_raw_data = response.read()
    return variable_for_raw_data
```

If you don't know about [`if **name** == '**main**':](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/322909) you should read up on it.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Don't forget to use meaningful variable names and not override the
[builtins](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) (i.e. file = "foo.txt" would override the file builtin)

```
    file_name = input("What will this data be saved as: ")
    html_from_website = htmlfrom("www.stackoverflow.com")
```

You can learn more about context managers [here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

```
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f: 
        f.write(html_from_website)
```

An edit using `globals()`, **FOR WHICH NO USE CASE EXISTS AT ALL**.

```
def htmlfrom(website_url):
    import urllib.request
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(website_url)
    variable_for_raw_data =(input("What will this data be saved as: "))
    globals()[variable_for_raw_data] = response.read()
```

Comment: How do I make it so that whatever I type in: input("What will this data be saved as: ")  becomes the variable?

Comment: It's generally considered bad to do this, so don't =). But `globals()["my_shiny_variable"] = "a_shiny_variable"` then `print my_shiny_variable`.

Comment: could you post the code how it would look.  I think you mean:  def htmlfrom(website_url):
    import urllib.request
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(website_url)
    variable_for_raw_data =(input("What will this data be saved as: "))
    globals()["my_shiny_variable"] = "a_shiny_variable"
    my_shiny_variable = response.read()

Comment: You are very helpful by the way.

Comment: can anyone help me with this?  I need for the variable that I enter in the the input prompt to trigger the HTML rather than the "x" variable.

Comment: for example, when I write:  def html(website_url):
    import urllib.request
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(website_url)
    x = input("Enter variable: ")
    x = response.read()                           When I type in whatever variable I type in the input after the function it just gives me an error.  How do I make what I type become the variable?