# call method without args from argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have a method I call from the command line using argparse. I also want to call that method from another method, in this case I get an error saying args is not defined. Is there a way around this, I have tried setting a default but I get the same error.

```
def change_modem_bank(bank_num=None, modem=None):  
    if args.sim_bank and args.modem_num:
        bank_num = args.sim_bank
        modem = args.modem_num  
    if "1" in bank_num:
        print "2" 
    elif "2" in bank_num:
         print "2"
    print modem

if __name__=='__main__':            
    parser_mode = subparsers.add_parser('set_modem_bank')
    parser_mode.add_argument('-bank',dest='sim_bank',help='SIM bank number',nargs='?',const=None,default=None)
    parser_mode.add_argument('-modem_num',dest='modem_num',help='Modem number',nargs='?',const=None,default=None)
    parser_mode.set_defaults(func=change_modem_bank)
    args=parser.parse_args()
    args.func()
```

I want to call the method like so from another script:

```
import cellular_modem
cellular_modem.change_modem_bank("2","0")
```

Currently I can call it like this:

```
myscript.py set_modem_bank -bank ${num}  -modem ${modem_num}
```

I would like it to work with either type of call, from CLI and from inside a python script.

Comment: Why is this downvoted/attempted to be closed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling functions with argparse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050920/calling-functions-with-argparse)

Comment: You need to give us more context.  Where do you normally call `args=parser.parse_args`.

Comment: @hpaulj it is called from main. So when in call it from CLI it works fine, I'll edit that into my code

Comment: Make it clear how your method gets access to `args` in that `main` case.

Comment: @hpaulj I edited now, does that clear it up? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call it as a script, what happens is:

```
args=parser.parse_args()
change_modem_bank() # equivalent to args.func()
```

When you import the module, that `main` part is skipped, so `args` is not set.  If you want to call `change_modem_back` as is, then you need to create an `args` variable that looks like the one that the parser would generate.  Here's one way of doing that:

```
import cellular_modem
import argparse
args = argparse.Namepspace(simbank=xxx, modem_num=xxx)
cellular_modem.change_modem_bank("2","0")
```

Your function assumes that, in its global argument space there is an object with these 2 attributes:

```
args.sim_bank, args.modem_num
```

You change the function to something like:

```
def change_modem_bank(bank_num=None, modem=None, args=None):  
    if args and args.sim_bank and args.modem_num:
        bank_num = args.sim_bank
        modem = args.modem_num
```

and invoke it in the `main` as:

```
args.func(args=args)
```

This way it is clear where the function is getting its `args` variable from.  It also behaves rationally when `args` is a simple default value like `None`.

One way or other you need to initialize an `args` variable when importing, and then write your function is a way that it will be ok with that default version.

Comment: Thanks great answer, unfortunately doens't work in my case as then all functions would need at least one argument from args=args and most of them don't have one. Will work it out!

Comment: solved it with a wrapper function, cheers for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your `change_modem_bank` function tries to access `args` directly, which works when you call it as a command-line script since it's in the module namespace then, but fails when you call it separately. Just fix it to get args passed in instead:

```
def change_modem_bank(bank_num, modem):  
    if "1" in bank_num:
        print "2" 
    elif "2" in bank_num:
         print "2"
    print modem
```

And call it with:

```
args.func(args.sim_bank, args.modem_num)
```

You'll have to figure out what your function is supposed to do if the arguments are `None`, since that will cause an error now.