# Setting the value of a global variable in the context of a function raises UnboundLocalError?

Tags: python

Maybe my coffee is not strong enough this morning, but this behavior is confusing me right now:

```
>>> a = 'foo'
>>> def func1():
...   print a
... 
>>> def func2():
...   print a
...   a = 'bar'
... 
>>> func1()
foo
>>> func2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in func2
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

(Note that it's the `print a` statement that's raising the error in `func2()`, not `a = 'bar'`.)

Can somebody explain to me what's going on here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146359/python-scope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `a` is being set inside `func2`, Python assumes it's a local variable. Put a `global a` declaration before the `print` statement:

```
def func2():
    global a
    print a
    a = 'bar'
```

See also [this question about Python scoping rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it. I so very rarely use global variables in Python that I have yet to stumble across this.