# Python guesses my number (reverse number guess) UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, python-2.7

i'm trying to write a simple number guesser program. In this particular program, python is guessing a number the user is thinking of, not the other way round.

My code returns an UnboundLoalError.

Also, it all seems too long and cumbersome. How can I shorten it?

Thank you.

```
# Guesses a number

from random import randint
number = ""

def numberGuesser():
    while True:
        print "Think of a number between 1 and 50"
        raw_input("Hit a key when ready")
        number = randint(1,50)
        answer = raw_input("Is your number: %d?. y/n> " % number)
        if answer == 'y':
            print "Great!"
            raw_input("Hit a key to exit.")
        elif answer == 'n':
            greater_or_smaller()
        else:
            print "Please type y or n"



def greater_or_smaller():
    while True:
        greater_or_smaller = raw_input("Is\
 your number greater or smaller than %d? g/s> " % number)
        if greater_or_smaller == 'g':
            number = randint(number, 50)
            answer = raw_input("Is your number %d? y/n> " % number)
            if answer == 'y':
                print "Hooray!"
            elif answer == 'n':
                greater_or_smaller()

        elif greater_or_smaller == 's':
            number = randint(1, number)
            answer = raw_input("Is your number %d? y/n> " % number)
            if answer == 'y':
                print "Hooray!"
            elif answer == 'n':
                greater_or_smaller()


numberGuesser()
```

Comment: Pay attention to errors python gives you. You will see a line where it appeared, and based on the name of the error you can find out what the actual error is pretty quickly. Also it'd be better if you pass `number` as parameter and get rid of global variables.

Comment: @millimoose as I said, short answer :) I wrote another comment with expanded answer. I think I'll delete my first comment now.

Comment: Also: you're using a variable named `greater_or_smaller` in a function with the same name. This is generally a bad idea. In your case, since you call the function recursively, it's a bad idea (i.e. a bug) specifically - you'll attempt to "call" the `str` you read in.

Comment: As for making your code shorter - this is subtly off-topic for SO. That said, notice that in `greater_or_smaller()` both branches of the `if greater_or_smaller == …:` block are almost identical except for the values passed to `randint()`. You can get rid of the duplication by just moving the shared code outside that block.

Comment: (Sorry for posting comments instead of a full answer, but I'm on the phone which makes writing proper answers a chore.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting the value of a global variable in the context of a function raises UnboundLocalError?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354911/setting-the-value-of-a-global-variable-in-the-context-of-a-function-raises-unbou)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This :

```
        if greater_or_smaller == 'g':
            number = randint(number, 50)
            answer = raw_input("Is your number %d? y/n> " % number)
            if answer == 'y':
                print "Hooray!"
            elif answer == 'n':
                greater_or_smaller()

        elif greater_or_smaller == 's':
            number = randint(1, number)
            answer = raw_input("Is your number %d? y/n> " % number)
            if answer == 'y':
                print "Hooray!"
            elif answer == 'n':
                greater_or_smaller()
```

could be :

```
        if greater_or_smaller in ['g','s']:
            number = randint(number, 50) if greater_or_smaller == 'g' else randint(1, number)
            answer = raw_input("Is your number %d? y/n> " % number)
            if answer == 'y':
                print "Hooray!"
            elif answer == 'n':
                greater_or_smaller()
```

Also, you should probably write a little function to handle the interactions with the user to ensure the answer is included in the list of expected answers.

Something like :

```
def get_input(prompt_text, valid_options):
    x = raw_input(prompt_text)
    while x not in valid_options:
        print x, "is not a valid value. Expected are :", valid_options
    return x
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this error because the function `greater_or_smaller` uses the variable `number` in the `raw_input` call, then *later* assigns to it. Put `global number` at the top of your function and the error will go away. (But then listen to the other advice you're getting here).

**Explanation:** To assign to or modify a global variable, you must first declare it global. (You can use a global/non-local variable without declaring it global, as long as you don't assign to it anywhere in your function).