# Python: Returning a list doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.4

I am trying to make a program that can add/delete/show students in a class, and the 5 classes are 5 lists in a list.

**Help is greatly appreciated.**

When  I run this code:

```
global classes
def intro():
    print("Welcome to Powerschool v2.0!")
    print("Actions:")
    print("1. Add Student")
    print("2. Delete Student")
    print("3. Show Students in a Class")
    print("4. Show All Students")
    x = int(input())
    while x<1 or x>4:
        print ("Please choose an action, 1-4.")
        x = int(input())
    if x == 1:
        action1()
    elif x == 2:
        action2()
    elif x == 3:
        action3()
    elif x == 4:
        action4()
    classes = [[],[],[],[],[]]
    return classes
def action1():
    print("Which Class? 1-5")
    a = int(input())
    print("Please enter the student's name.")
    z = input()
    classes[a-1].append(z)
    again()
def action2():
    print ("Which Class? 1-5")
    print ("Which student?")
    again()
def action3():
    print ("Which Class? 1-5")
    y = int(input())
    if y == 1:
        print (classes[0])
    elif y == 2:
        print (classes[1])
    elif y == 3:
        print (classes[2])
    elif y == 4:
        print (classes[3])
    elif y == 5:
        print (classes[4])
    again()
def action4():
    print (classes)
    again()
def again():
    print("Would you like to do something else? y/n")
    h = input()
    if h == "y":
        intro()
    else:
        quit
def main():

    intro()

main()
```

My error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\user1\My Documents\Downloads\az_studenttracker.py", line 67, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\user1\My Documents\Downloads\az_studenttracker.py", line 65, in main
    intro()
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\user1\My Documents\Downloads\az_studenttracker.py", line 19, in intro
    action1()
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\user1\My Documents\Downloads\az_studenttracker.py", line 33, in action1
    classes[a-1].append(z)
NameError: name 'classes' is not defined
```

I did `return classes` at the end of intro() but I see that doesn't work. 
I followed some suggestions, and nothing really happened :/

Comment: You are going out of scope when `classes[a-1].append(z)` because for that case, your `classes` haven't been defined. You are only getting classes after `def intro()` method.

Comment: Also i now realize I have no idea what return does. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `classes` is out of scope for the second two methods. Therefore, you have two options:

### Option 1

Pass classes to the methods `action1(), action2(), etc` like so:

`def action1(classes)`

...and the when you call it:

`action1(classes) //with the classes var you just made`

### Option 2 (recommended)

Simply put the `classes` var outside your methods or declare it `global` like so:

`global classes = [[],[],[],[],[]]`

...right before:

`def intro()`

**In general, you should read up on how return works; it is not necessary in the code you wrote**

Comment: It doesn't make sense to declare a variable as `global` when it's already at the global scope. You would use `global` on the local variable `classes` in `intro()` to make it globally-scoped without having to declare it there

Comment: I don't get this scope thing other than the fact that global is used across the whole program? and local is within that one def

Comment: @Player72 correct. That is all you need to know as far as scope is concerned in this problem

Comment: @Player72 No problem. You should read through this, it will help you considerably in grasping some concepts: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/

Answer (score 5):

You're defining `classes` in your `intro` method, and, even though it's returning it, your `action1` method doesn't see any variable named `classes` anywhere.

[Relevant answer on Python scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146359/python-scope) and [relevant documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).

Answer (score 2):

`return` doesn't do what you think it does. `return` statements are a way of passing execution control back up a context (For example, from `intro()` to `main()`), with the ability to send back some information for the higher context to use. Although you're passing `classes` back to `main()`, you never do anything with it at that context so it goes away.

One way to solve the problem would be to declare `classes` as a global variable. This is the easiest thing to do, but isn't generally good design. You could do this either by using the `global` keyword before declaring the local variable `classes` in `intro()` (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python) question for guidance on `global`), or by declaring `classes` outside any of your functions.

Another solution would be to pass `classes` as a parameter to your `action` functions.

In either case, you would need to declare `classes` before any calls to your `action` functions.

Answer (score 1):

`classes` only exists in `intro():`, you would have to declare it as a `global` variable to access it in other functions or declare it outside the function.

```
classes = [[],[],[],[],[]] # can be accessed by action3() ,action4()
def intro():
```