# Python2.7/Confused with variables

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
initial_p = input("Enter the initial point")

def game():
    x = 1
    guess = input("Guess value")
    if guess == 1:
        initial_p += 2
    else:
        initial_p -= 2

game()

replay = raw_input("Do you want to try it again? Y/N")
if replay == 'Y':
    game()
```

each game needs 2 points

I made it really simple just to explain this stuff easily

So to play each game, it requires you to have at least 2 points otherwise it becomes game over
if you guess right, you earn 2 points
if not, you lose 2 points.

with the outcome(points), you can either play again or quit

if you play again, you pay two points

HOWEVER, when you play for the second time or more, that line

`initial_p += 2` and `initial_p -= 2` still have points that you typed in the very beginning

Comment: Please correctly format your post. Apart from that, I think you are having problem understanding scope of the variables and not their names. `initial_p` appears to be a global variable currently but is accessed improperly.

Comment: Possible dupe or related to [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](http://stackoverflow.com/q/423379/2823755).  Another possible answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/370363/2823755. And http://stackoverflow.com/a/146365/2823755

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/2823755.  And finally from the Tutorial in the docs https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces

Comment: There are many problems with this code, and there is no coherent question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty response is to change to the following.

```
def game(initial_p):
    #Your Code
    return initial_p


initial_p = game(initial_p)
```

Basically, you're placing the global variable as a local variable and reassigning the global.

This should also happen at the very bottom as well.

Also, you can just ask for the input inside of the function, and have a default argument of `initial_p`.

For example,

```
def game(first_time=True)
    #Ask for input with if first_time:
    return initial_p
```

And modify some global point value or something from the return.

Sorry if this is sloppy, was written on my mobile.